# Polymorphic One to Many relationship is NULL

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm working on a Laravel project with subdomains. Each new company gets it own subdomain. Every client that is created inside a company needs to get the same subdomain.

Because it's possible that a subdomain will change over time I'm using a subdomain table.

So I have three tables and models: `Subdomain`, `Company` and `Client` and the following rules:

- A subdomain can have multiple organisations (Company or Client)
- A Company can have one subdomain
- A client can have one subdomain

Therefore I'm using a polymorphic One to Many relationship.

**create_subdomains_table Migration**

```
Schema::create('subdomains', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->morphs('organisation');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**create_companies_table Migration**

```
Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('enterprise_number')->unique();
    $table->string('legal_entity_type');
    $table->string('business_name');
    $table->string('phone');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->json('ancestry')->nullable();
    
    $table->bigInteger('subdomain_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('subdomain_id')->references('id')->on('subdomains');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Company Model**

```
public function subdomain() {
    return $this->morphOne(Subdomain::class, 'organisation');
}
```

**Subdomain Model**

```
public function organisation() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Create company controller function**

```
// Create subdomain
$subdomain = Subdomain::create([
    'name' => Str::slug($validatedData['business_name'], '-')
]);

// Create company
$company = Company::create([
    'enterprise_number' => $validatedData['enterprise_number'],
    'legal_entity_type' => $validatedData['legal_entity_type'],
    'business_name' => $validatedData['business_name'],
    'phone' => $validatedData['phone'],
    'email' => $validatedData['email'],
]);

// Create relationship between company and subdomain
$company->subdomain()->save($subdomain);
```

This results in an error `Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"organisation_type\" of relation \"subdomains\" violates not-null constraint`

Although I found `$table->morphs('organisation');` in the Laravel documentation I changed it to

```
$table->bigInteger('organisation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->string('organisation_type')->nullable();
```

This works to create a subdomain and company entry but the `subdomain_id` column in the companies table is NULL.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: the issue is with your key conventions

Answer (score 1):

'enterprise_number' => should the model id ex: `1`,
'legal_entity_type' => should the model namespace ex: `'App\Models\ModelName'`,